# Hooking up to an event within unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, testing, event-handling

I'm trying to run a unit test on a class that does some stuff on a separate thread and then notifies the parent that it has finished the task using an eventhandler.  This is my test code:

```
        [TestMethod()]
    public void InitTest()
    {
        Controller target = new Controller();
        target.FinishedCommand += delegate(bool success)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(true, success);
        };
        target.Init();
        while (true)
        {

        }
    }
```

And this is the method I am testing:

```
public delegate void ControllerEventHandler(bool success);
public class Controller
{
    public event ControllerEventHandler FinishedCommand;
    public void Init()
    {
        FinishedCommand(true);
    }
}
```

I realize that Init() doesn't use a new thread, but I'm just trying to make sure the test is running now.  Instead of passing, the test just gets stuck in the while() loop forever, and the anonymous delegate is never entered.

Is the event hooked up incorrectly?  Can events be used like this in Unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

`Assert` does not stop the test, and tests do not fail if an `Assert` statement is not executed - so the `while(true)` loop keeps your test from finishing.

Furthermore events behave like simple method calls - so before `target.Init();` returns, the event has already occurred.

You should probably use a variable `bool eventOccurredAndSucceeded = false` which you can set in the event handler, and simply test it after calling `target.Init();`:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void InitTest()
    {
        bool eventOccurredAndSucceeded = false;
        Controller target = new Controller();
        target.FinishedCommand += delegate(bool success)
        {
            if (success)
            {
                eventOccurredAndSucceeded = true;
            }
        };

        target.Init();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, eventOccurredAndSucceeded);
    }
```

Comment: So the problem with *not* leveraging the `ManualResetEvent` class here is that there is a race condition in which the test will succeed sometimes and fail others.

Comment: You may be correct on that. The `ManualResetEvent` may not be necessary here since `Init` raises the event directly.

Answer (score 1):

Events can be tested, but the best way I've found is using the `ManualResetEvent`. Consider this modification:

```
public void InitTest()
{
    Controller target = new Controller();
    target.FinishedCommand += delegate(bool success)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(true, success);
        eventRaised.Set();
    };

    ManualResetEvent eventRaised = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    target.Init();

    eventRaised.WaitOne();
}
```

What happens here is the `WaitOne` will stop this methods execution waiting for the `Set()` to be called. Since the `Set()` gets called inside the event handler, it waits logically until the event is raised and asserted.

However, you're going to have to move your `Assert` outside the event handler because the method won't succeed otherwise, so there is one more slight modification required:

```
public void InitTest()
{
    bool succeeded = false;
    Controller target = new Controller();
    target.FinishedCommand += delegate(bool success)
    {
        succeeded = success;
        eventRaised.Set();
    };

    ManualResetEvent eventRaised = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    target.Init();

    eventRaised.WaitOne();
    Assert.IsTrue(succeeded);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My example didn't actually use a separate thread, but I will be implementing that and your answer was helpful.